# User List in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Hi All I am verey new to SP2007. If I dont want to use AD as my source for user infomation how would I go about making a custom user database.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you need is **forms-based authentication**.

It's a very broad topic, so read about the basics:

- [Configure forms-based authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262201%28office.12%29.aspx)
- [Forms Authentication in SharePoint Products and Technologies (Part 1): Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136%28office.12%29.aspx)
- [Forms Authentication in SharePoint Products and Technologies (Part 2): Membership and Role Provider Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975135%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Forms Authentication in SharePoint Products and Technologies (Part 3): Forms Authentication vs. Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977430%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

check this implementation using ASP.NET forms authentication:

- [CKS Forms Based Authentication Solution](http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/17901)

and then return with more questions.